# updated Spyder - how to load my mpl style & import module?

Tags: plot, import, spyder

Working on Mac M1Pro with Sonoma 14.3. Updated Spyder IDE 5.5.0 {Python 3.9.14 64-bit | Qt 5.15.11 | PyQt5 5.15.10} and all hell broke loose. Two major problems when running py script:
1)

```
from   decode_Drivers import (power_fit, decode_name, create_file_list)
```

decode_Drivers is in the same folder as the py script I am running.
Gives me error:

File /Applications/Spyder.app/Contents/Resources/lib/python3.9/spyder_kernels/py3compat.py:356 in compat_exec
exec(code, globals, locals)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'decode_Drivers'

2. And then when:

```
plt.style.use('katerina.mplstyle')
```

I get:
File /Applications/Spyder.app/Contents/Resources/lib/python3.9/spyder_kernels/py3compat.py:356 in compat_exec
exec(code, globals, locals)

File /Applications/Spyder.app/Contents/Resources/lib/python3.9/matplotlib/style/core.py:139 in use
raise OSError(
OSError: 'katerina.mplstyle' is not a valid package style, path of style file, URL of style file, or library style name (library styles are listed in `style.available`)

I have no idea how to fix these two....
Any help in layman terms would be appreciated.

While I could manually bring in the contents of my whole decode_Drivers file instead of importing it, I could not do anything about the mpl.

Comment: Sounds like your working directory isn't set correctly. Right-click on the title tab for your script and choose `Set console working directory` before running it. Check `Tools` > `Preferences` > `Run`, maybe these settings changed in the upgrade.